# When height of content is more then min-height

Tags: css

I've a header and a footer. In the middle a constant left- and right-part, and in the middle my content-part. The height of the content-part is changing.
I don't succeed in my attempts to place the footer below the content-part when the height of the content-part is more then a min-height.

This is the code of my attempts:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #page{
     width:800px;
     border:1px solid black;
     margin:5px auto;
     background:#e2ebed;
    }
    
    #header{
     height:100px;
     background:yellow;
    }
    
    #center{
     min-height:300px;
     background:lightblue;
    }
    
    #left{
     float:left;
     width:150px;
     background:aquamarine ;
    }
    
    #content{
     float:left;
     width:500px;
    // min-height:300px;
     background:cornflowerblue;
    }
    
    #right{
     float:left;
     width:150px;
     background:aquamarine;
    }
    
    #footer{
     height:50px;
     background:red;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="page">
     <div id="header">
      Header
     </div>
    
     <div id="center">
      <div id="left">
       Left
      </div>
    
      <div id="content">
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
       Content<br>
      </div>
    
      <div id="right">
       Right
      </div>
     </div>
    
     <div id="footer">
      Footer
     </div>
    <div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The `#page` div is not closed properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the float, so I added this rule

```
#center:after{
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
#page{
    width:800px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:5px auto;
    background:#e2ebed;
}
#header{
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
}
#center{
    min-height:300px;
    background:lightblue;
}
#center:after{
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#left{
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    background:aquamarine ;
}
#content{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    min-height:300px;
    background:cornflowerblue;
}
#right{
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    background:aquamarine;
}
#footer{
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <div id="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div id="center">
        <div id="left">
            Left
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
            Content<br>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: @swaenie You're welcome, and if my answer solved your question, please accept it as well

Comment: Yes, your answer solved my question. But I'm sorry, how do I accept your answer?

Comment: @swaenie At the top left side of my answer is a check mark you click on, which becomes green showing it is the accepted answer.